# Table foreign key points to one of two tables

Tags: entity-framework, code-first, foreign-key-relationship

This is my first post so please excuse me if I didn't follow the correct procedure.
Also note that I have only started learning EF-Code First this week so I'm very new to it and don't really understand all the solutions on stackoverflow.

The problem:
I have three classes: User, Tenant and Dashboard.
A dashboard can only be for either a User or a Tenant.
In other words, a user has a dashboard and a tenant has a dashboard.
It is always a one-to-one relationship between User and Dashboard.
The same goes for Tenant and Dashboard.

How would one go about to create these relationships?

I have read through a lot of the data annotation methods as well as the fluent api methods but I have to admit am still dumbfounded as to how to get it going.

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public int TenantId { get; set; }
    public virtual Tenant Tenant { get; set; }
}

public class Tenant
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Dashboard
{
    [Key]
    public int DashboardId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: You are saying that user has one-to-one relationship with dashboard. But your user class has navigation property for tenant and nothing for dashboard

Comment: Yes this is true, it is merely an example of the two clases. I have removed the data-annotations as they didn't work. Kinda hoped I could give an example of the "uncompleted classes" and then someone can help me out with how to go about "filling them in". Hope that makes sense.

Comment: In your case,user and tenant both will have a foreign key of dashboard. Given that dashboards table data created prior to users.

Answer (score 0):

In the following both Users and Tenants have a single dashboard

```
public class User
{
    public int UserId {get; set;}
    public virtual Dashboard Dashboard {get; set;}
}

public class Tenant
{
    public int TenantId {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public virtual Dashboard Dashboard {get; set;}
}

public class Dashboard
{
    public int DashboardId {get; set;}
    public string Description {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: Hi again. Sorry for the slow reply. Only got to testing this today. Problem is when adding the migration I get the following error:

"Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the types 'BOF365WebApp.Models.User' and 'BOF365_Solution.Models.XC365Core.Dashboard.Dashboard'. The principal end of this association must be explicitly configured using either the relationship fluent API or data annotations."